# FFServer does not stop

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, ffserver

I am trying to stream video from my webcam to a website that I created, using FFMpeg and FFServer on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.  I can successfully start FFServer with an ffserver1.conf file I've made, but when I stop FFServer (with crtl+c) to make changes to my config file, and try to start FFServer again, I get an error: ***Could not start server***.  Then I try to start the server with the default ffserver.conf (in /etc), I get an error: ***bind(port 8090): Address already in use***.  Sometimes I also get ***Deleting feed file "/tmp/feed1.ffm' as stream counts differ (4 != 1)***.

It seems to me that the server is not completely stopping when I kill it in the terminal with ctrl+c.  Is there another way to stop FFServer?  Or should I just get a different version - I'm currently using version **0.10.11-7:0.10.11-1~precisce1**.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, ffserver doesn't stop. One way to stop ffserver is by killing ffserver process by running the following commands.

The command below shows the ports in use (you can confirm that port 8090 is still in use).

```
netstat -tulnap
```

Then, you can kill process you want (ffserver in your case) and release the port as well by running:

```
sudo fuser -k 8090/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

may be your main ffserver thread is not yet killed.
try this:
you can see all threads of ubuntu with :

`ps -ux`

and then use comand 'kill' the previous main thread like this:

`kill %X`

X is the thread number

note:if you've got a error 'permission denied', use `sudo` at the first of each comand.

see this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104903/how-do-i-kill-processes-in-ubuntu)